# How to position light source so it reflects off gold Celtic knot on the sword guard, into the camera?

Tags: camera

[image: Anvil and sword]How do I find the perfect position for the light so that it will reflect off the Celtic knot? There are 3 light sources I can't find the sweet spot. I've tried moving them around of course. I've tried spot, point, sun at an angle about = to the camera angle to sword face. I either bleach out the scene or it just has no effect if I play with size and brightness. I need that sweet spot angle, and I just can't find it. Here is blender 2.79 file, https://www.dropbox.com/s/evlsqvdtpet39ml/anvil2blend.blend?dl=0
Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

I realized after exploring that if I placed a point light close to the object I wanted to light up, (gold Celtic Knot) that it would light up nicely. What I couldn't wrap my head around is that the light source itself never shows up in a render so it can be placed in the visual field of the camera. Duh! This way it can be relatively small and of low intensity, which for some reason I think is better that having some light source a mile away at 100,000 intensity and sized at 1000. I found that I could place the light source right on the object for instance and it worked well.